# Flask hot reload not working in docker, the log indicates otherwise

Tags: python, docker, flask, pycharm, hot-reload

I run the following `docker-compose.yml` in PyCharm, which runs `docker-compose up`

```
version: '3'

services:
  posts:
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    image: flask-blog-posts
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'posts/Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
  comments:
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    image: flask-blog-comments
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'comments/Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
```

which in turn starts `posts` and `comments` services and the debugger is expected to detect changes in code and reload whenever this happens. Here's the log for `posts` service:

```
* Debug mode: on
2022-09-22T17:17:44.094571019Z WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
2022-09-22T17:17:44.094599147Z  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
2022-09-22T17:17:44.094603187Z  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001
2022-09-22T17:17:44.094606086Z  * Running on http://172.18.0.3:5001
2022-09-22T17:17:44.094809796Z Press CTRL+C to quit
2022-09-22T17:17:44.096079648Z  * Restarting with stat
2022-09-22T17:17:44.498014077Z  * Debugger is active!
2022-09-22T17:17:44.499326875Z  * Debugger PIN: 643-209-648
2022-09-22T17:18:11.411390459Z 172.18.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2022 17:18:11] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2022-09-22T17:18:13.610573254Z 172.18.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2022 17:18:13] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2022-09-22T17:19:12.423894271Z 172.18.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2022 17:19:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

it clearly indicates that the debugger is active however, when I make changes in the corresponding app code, nothing happens and changes go undetected. The directory looks like the following:

```
├── README.md
├── comments
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── posts
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
└── templates
```

`posts/app.py` and `comments/app.py` contain the same code as below:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and here's both docker files which are pretty much the same as well except for the ports `5001` and `5002` for posts and comments respectively.

```
FROM python:3.10
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR comments
CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5001"]
```

I need that whenever I make any changes in the code, it should reflect and reload accordingly. The current behavior: I make changes in any of `app.py`s, ex: change `Hello world!` to `Hello earth!`, if I refresh the page 50 times, I'll still get `Hello world`. I tried rebuilding both containers, restarting docker, deleting configuration files, ... nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your code is copied to a container & then that container is running the code. The changes you make are outside of container to your system. If you wish to let the changes reflect, you will need to add a volume in the file as below ::

```
version: '3'

services:
  posts:
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    image: flask-blog-posts
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'posts/Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
  comments:
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    image: flask-blog-comments
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: 'comments/Dockerfile'
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
```

In this way, when you make changes to the ./local_path directory, they will reflect in the container.

---

Update - Adding exact changes for other files as well

posts & comments Dockerfiles -

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR comments
CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=5001"]
```

Comment: What does `./local_path:/container_path/to/code_dir` mean? Let's say that the root dir is in `/Users/example-user/Desktop`, what should be the value in `volumes`?

Comment: in case your code is in same directory as your docker-compose file, then a simple `.` should do it i.e. `- .:/container/code` The `/container/code` depends on the dockerfile .. the location where the code is copied inside container. I would suggest adding a `WORKDIR /code` before `COPY . .` in Dockerfiles. And then you could use `/code` in the volumes.

Comment: Either I'm tired or experiencing a severe decline in my cognitive abilities or both. In either case, can you please check the directory structure included in the question and let me know what value I need to use in `volumes`. You can assume the root dir lives in `/Users/example-user/Desktop`. I tried what I understood from your suggestions and it didn't work.

Comment: Sure, @shindig ; I have updated the code for 3 files - docker-compose.yml, and the 2 Dockerfiles for posts & comments. Please try the same..

Comment: The Dockerfile should no longer `COPY` everything. It should only copy `requirements.txt`

Comment: @iArc13 thanks, i'll check as soon as I have a laptop.

Comment: @noslenkwah if everything is not copied, I get a `unable to import app` error.

Comment: You dont copy you code, you need to mount your code. The mounting of the code is what will enable reloading with the debugger. If you are getting an import error on your app, its likely something is in the wrong directory.